# Cut files in ForkLift 2

Tags: keyboard, finder, file-transfer

I decided to give ForkLift 2 a try, since it is currently on sale in MAS. I've been using XtraFinder to enable normal (Cmd+X) file cut operation in Finder.

Now that I'm trying to move to ForkLift I can't find a way to make this command work.
No shortcut in the preferences can be set for the operation. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Finder doesn't have a cut  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>   behaviour for files, only for file names.

It uses Edit menu > Copy
or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>

then Edit menu holding  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  > Move Item Here
or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  instead.

... or Drag holding  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  between volumes

Comment: I know, that Finder doesn't have that functionality by default. As I've mentioned, I use the XtraFinder plugin to add that functionality. Now I'm wondering how I can do the same with ForkLift.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Forklift manual](http://wiki.binarynights.com)...

> Copy
>
> To copy the item(s) selected in the active pane to the folder opened in the opposite pane you can use the following methods:
>
> - click the toolbar icon
> - select File > Copy to from the menu
> - use the cmd-c keyboard command to copy the item(s) to the clipboard, then switch to the second pane with TAB and use cmd-v to paste
> - copy is also available in the item list context menu
> - the commander style keybinding set allows the use of F5 for 'copy to'.

Comment: I thought I had put it straight enough that I wanted to have `Cmd+X` in ForkLift. It's faster to `mv` in the shell if I can't just `Cmd+X` in the file manager.

Comment: Then put the details in your question. I've had enough of chasing answers for you that you didn't specify you'd tried or eliminated in your question.

Comment: I'll undelete my previous answers to save anyone else wasting their time.

Comment: My question clearly states "Now that I'm trying to move to ForkLift I can't find a way to make this command (Cmd+X) work. No shortcut in the preferences can be set for the operation. Is there a workaround?" I can't see how one can state it more obviously, that I need to set a shortcut (Cmd+X) for the file cut operation in ForkLift (like it is possible to do in Finder using XtraFinder). You should've read the question before trying to answer.

Comment: I'll let the community decide.

Answer (score 0):

There is no usual Cmd+X but you still can achieve the same behaviour.

Press Command-C to copy then Command-Option-V to move, or choose File > Copy then File > Move Items Here while holding the Option key.

Pay attention to Command-Option-V
It will move the file! Similar to how Cmd+X does that.